# play multiple flv file in single swf object

Tags: flash, swfobject, flvplayback

I have one swf object in my site.

I have to read data from database and after fetching data of video names,

I need to play those video in single swf object one by one, means after completion of first video second video will start.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what player are you trying to play the flvs in? The player is going to need to be able to support playing multiple videos or you would have to rembed the player with the next video after the first video is complete. In the later case, the player would need to do an ExternalInterface call to let your Javascript code know when a video is complete.

Comment: So how would i know that my video is completed or not?
I am using below version swf js file to embed my video.
SWFObject v1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply we can create a playlist for that...

Some googeling helps me for this.

[check out this](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forum/Setup-Problems/8917/create-my-xml-playlist-to-work-with-flv-player)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using NetStream, you have to listen to NetStream [onPlayStatus](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/NetStream.html#event:onPlayStatus) event and then load another flv with the [play(...)](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/NetStream.html#play%28%29) method

Answer (score 0):

Lee Brimelow has a tutorial here for building your own video player in AS3, this should help to get you started - though from the way you're talking about it I get the sense that you're not really a flash developer, you just have to work with flash for this project - so what you're asking for may be a little more complex than you expect.

First watch this:

http://gotoandlearn.com/play?id=46

Then understand that when you build a player it fires certain "events" at certain times. Like kajyr above says, you need to listen for a specific event that tells you that the current clip is over. When that even fires, you have to tell your player to play the next clip.

What you're asking for is entirely possible and even easy if you understand the basics behind it. I built a tool that handles dynamic playlisting etc at my old job and it only took about a day to give it every feature we needed. But you do need to understand how AS3 works in order to make this work.

Alternately you may be able to find some sort of video sequencing app at http://activeden.net/ - they have a lot of pre-built flash components and that's another way to go.